# Test suite control repositories and change

Tags: java, junit4

I'm trying to find some java code with it's test suites, which includes all changes happen to test cases overtime(adding updating and deleting) after updating the code. Where do you think I could find this kind of repository that track changes to the source code and it's test cases over time.

Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to divide your needs into separate categories, and then find tools that cover the category.

```
I'm trying to find some java code with it's test suites, which includes all changes happen
to test cases overtime(adding updating and deleting) after updating the code.
```

A source code control system tracks changes to all revisioned files over time.  There are many different source code control systems, but if you are starting out in source code control the documentation is more important than the specific system.  I suggest subversion, [which has excellent documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf).

Under such a system, source code is checked in, which allows tracking of changes over time.  Typically test cases are also checked in (usually in a different directory) and changes in test cases are also tracked over time.

Subversion is not the only solution, almost any source code control system will do this task.  I recommend subversion because you are likely to see it again, it has excellent documentation, and some of the most advertised features of other systems are not understood until some mastery of source code control is obtained.

The actual source code is another matter.  I think you want to write your own, but if you are looking for someone else's source code, there are many projects at apache.org or sourceforge which give some examples of how other people solved their problems using a source code control system.

```
Where do you think I could find this kind of repository that track changes to the source
code and it's test cases over time.
```

You can find subversion at http://subversion.apache.org/, and if you don't want to install your own private subversion server, you can find hosting providers which will install and run your subversion server (for a fee).  I recommend you install your own server at least once, and to start I would also recommend the `svnserve` version of the server.  After you get a feel for how source code control works under subversion, you might consider a `https` installation.